# How to convert JSON dates to Calender format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date

I'm trying to insert events into a calendar. the problem is my events are structured like this: `xx/xx/xxxx` and the calendar uses another format 
`xx-xx-xxxx`. How do I make this transformation ?

I have transformed the dates from JSON format to a string but I can't change the `/` into `-`.

```
data.forEach(function (element) {

    let date = new Date(element.sessionDate)
    datesArr.push(date.toLocaleDateString())
})

console.log(datesArr)
```

And now my array looks like this:

> 0: "12/24/2018"
>
> 1: "12/27/2018"
>
> 2: "1/3/2019"
>
> 3: "1/3/2019"
>
> 4: "1/7/2019"

My expected result for the calendar to receive the events should be: `['2019-03-04', '2019-03-08', '2019-03-12', '2019-03-15']`.

Comment: you can change the date format with datePipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: the fastest way would be to use moment.js. I know it's another dependency, but it saves you a lot of headache with string manipulation: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: What is "JSON format" for a date, there's nothing in the spec for dates!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

### The array version

You could replace them using a regex and then glue matched values back together.

```js
const input = '12/24/2018';
const parts = input.split('/');
const output = `${parts[2]}-${parts[0]}-${parts[1]}`;

console.log(new Date(output));
```

---

### The regex version

You could replace them using a regex and then glue matched values back together.

```js
const input = '12/24/2018';
const output = input.replace(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/, '$3-$1-$2');

console.log(new Date(output));
```

---

### Or using a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Split the string value by "/" separation gives an array of results. Then join the array with "-" to get the string result back. Use Array.map() to transform into a new array.

```
const dates = ['2019/03/04', '2019/03/08', '2019/03/12', '2019/03/15'];

const formattedDates = dates.map( date => date.split("/").join("-"));

console.log(formattedDates); //["2019-03-04", "2019-03-08", "2019-03-12", "2019-03-15"]
```

Comment: hi. can i share my code with you so you can help me insert that solution into it?

Comment: Yes, please share. I would like to help you.